# Definition of a function-valued measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am familiar with the classical definition of a measure where for a measure $\mu$ we have $$\mu: X_\sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$$
where $X_\sigma$ is the $\sigma$-algebra associated to some space $X$. We can extend this notion by introducing signed measures so that $\mu$ now takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. Such a measure is easy to construct by defining $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ where $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are classical (non-negative) measures.

My question is regarding a further extension of this topic to "function-valued" measures, where I now want
$$\mu: X_\sigma \rightarrow Y$$
where $Y$ is now some function space (with possible restrictions, if so, what restrictions?). Does such a notion exist, and if so, how is it defined/constructed exactly? My motivation for this question was looking at projection-valued measures, where the range is now a set of projection operators, and began wondering if this can also be done for other functions spaces or even a vector space. I assume the answer is yes, but an explicit definition is eluding me. Any relevant resources will also be appreciated.

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure ?

Comment: @LL3.14 Thank you, this seems very close to what I am looking for.